# Can PHP's interactive mode run code in a namespace?

Tags: php, class, namespaces, interactive-shell

While in PHP's interactive mode, I tried the following:

```
php > namespace MyNamespace;
php > class Throwable {}
```

This results in a fatal error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot declare class Throwable, because the name is already in use in php shell code on line 1
```

However, the following code, when in a PHP file, executes without errors:

```
<?php
namespace MyNamespace;
class Throwable {}
```

Therefore, is it possible to somehow set a namespace while in interactive mode? Or, is all code in interactive mode run in the global space regardless of a previous namespace definition?

Comment: It working with namespace brackets. So `namespace MyNamespace { class Throwable {}  }` is working without errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work, you have to apply the [example given in the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definitionmultiple.php#example-251) that allows for combining namespaced and unnamespaced code:

```
namespace MyNamespace {
    class Throwable {}
}
```

It looks like this when you type it:

```
> namespace Mynamespace {
{ class Throwable {}
{ }
>
```

Comment: Wonderful. I forgot all about bracketed syntax for namespaces. Thank you.